# Predicting availability on a bike station

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I finally decided to start learning ML, to do so I am trying to predict the availability of bikes of my city's public bike sharing system.

- [Dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkwp79nqbfjsx62/Zunzunegi.txt?dl=1) (1MB) for one bike station. Columns: date, weekday, id, station, free_bikes, free_docks

I've been following Machine Learning Mistery's [tutorials](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) with Keras, in this case one for multivariate time series forecasting LSTM, which I think is adequate for my problem.

Currently, I am training the NN feeding it with: weekday(t-1), free_bikes(t-1) and free_bikes(t).

The loss and val_loss [graph](https://imgur.com/a/H0Qsj) I think looks good(ish). If I am not mistaken a RMSE of 0.9 is that I'll probably have an error or 1 bike when making predictions.

If all that is correct I'll also like to give the NN the date the sample was taken but I run into some problems I don't know I can solve. Adding an extra column I get this kind of error:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5949,2) (3,) (5949,2)`

To add the date into the problem I'll just delete the part on line 63 that says `index_col = 0` when reading the file.

Is it correct to add the date to improve the prediction and how should it be done?

- [script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u859ws5wopk5jpk/script.py?dl=1)

Comment: Could you name those columns, also which column are you trying to predict?

Comment: The columns are date, weekday, id, station, free_bikes, free_docks and I am trying to predict free_bikes (bike availability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line  `values = values.astype('float32')` converts all columns to float , so all the columns should be number like format.
Your 2 column `Weekday` is converted to integer using this line

`values[:, 0] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:, 0])`

This line makes 0th(First) Column to integer. Here your first column is date.

**Solution:**
Just convert 2nd column to integer

Add this line after the above line

```
values[:, 1] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:, 1])
```

Now to answer your 2nd Question

> Is it correct to add the date to improve the prediction and how should it be done?

No it is not. You can use just month which would be great instead of time-date